# gcc --version-script cannot recognize int64_t

Tags: c++, compilation

The code examples explain the problem fairly straightforward:

Hash.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

class Hash {
public:
    Hash(int64_t sz);
    int64_t size;
};
```

Hash.cpp

```
#include "Hash.h"

using namespace std;

Hash::Hash(int64_t sz) : size(sz)
{
    cout << "Hash int" << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Hash.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Hash HashTable(12);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the version file, foo.map:

```
VER_0.1
{
  global:
    extern "C++" {
        "Hash::Hash(int64_t)";
    };
  local:
    *;
};
```

For the compilation:

```
$g++ -g -c -Wall -Werror -fpic Hash.cpp -std=c++0x
$g++ -shared -o Hash.so Hash.o -std=c++0x -Wl,--version-script=foo.map
$g++ -g -o prog Hash.so main.cpp -std=c++0x
```

The error message:

```
/tmp/ccd60Ulm.o: In function `main':
/remote/ltg_engine1_us03/liangwa/test/004/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Hash::Hash(long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then if I change all int64_t to int or long, it compiles fine. So anything special with int64_t? I am using g++ 7.3.0

Comment: The fixed-width types in `<cstdint>` are just aliases, they are not native types of their own. `int64_t` is an alias for whatever native type the compiler uses as a 64-bit signed integer, whether that be `long`, `long long`, `__int64`, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That being said, version-script can only recognize the fundamental type. So aliases such as size_t cannot be used?

Comment: so it would seem, because aliases are resolved to their fully qualified types during compiling, and map files need to use the same symbol names that the compiler uses.  See [How To Write Shared Libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), Section 2.2.5, "Use Export Maps".